# How do I store an array nested in an object in React JS with useState?

Tags: reactjs

I am also using Axios for my API requests. I have a JSON response object like so:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "genres": ["Comedy", "Drama", "Romance"]
}
```

Using useState and useEffect:

```
const [movieDetails, setMovieDetails] = useState([]);
const [genres, setMovieGenre] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  retrieveMovieDetails();
  // The comment below disables missing dependency warning
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);

const retrieveMovieDetails = () => {
  movieDataSrv.getMovieDetailsById(id)
    .then(response => {
      setMovieDetails(response.data);
      setMovieGenre(response.data.genres);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('Error at retrieveMovieDetails(): ' + e);
    });
};
```

Note: `movieDetails._id` works properly when called.

I try to use it like so and receive an error type undefined for `movieDetails.genres`:

```
            <div className='genreContainer'>
                {movieDetails.genres.map((genre, i) => (
                    <div key={i} className='genreMapContainer'>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-info genreButton">{genre}</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
```

Using `genres`, however, works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it return an array or object in the response, as you initially define the state as an empty array but you then set it to whatever the response is, cannot use map on an object. What is returned?

Comment: @narliecholler I'm also using Axios, sorry for not pointing that out before, I edited my post. The response is an object like the one shown at the top. But ```movieDetails.genres``` is an array.

Comment: I guess it makes more sense to do ```const [movieDetails, setMovieDetails] = useState({});``` as an object but it makes no difference. It seemed it was automatically getting set as an object anyway.

Comment: The initial value of `movieDetails` is `[]`, so `movieDetails.genres` is `undefined`, and `movieDetails.genres.map` is ERROR. You either need to include a check to ensure you are only accessing `movieDetials.genres` when it actually has a value, or initialize `movieDetails` with something like `useState({ genres: [] })`

Comment: @JLRishe Using ```useState({ genres: [] })``` worked! Thank you! Unfortunately, I can't mark this as the answer as its a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems you are using `movieDetails.genres` before it is there in the state. Initially your state is an empty array hence doing `movieDetails.genres.map()` will give an `Cannot read property error`.

You can either initialise properly, that is keeping in check for respective properties you are going to use on `movieDetails` object or you can try adding

`movieDetails?.genres.map()`

This **Optional Chaining operator** will save you from causing an error and will map over the array once it is available.